# Proof that $\mathcal{L}$ contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{R}$.

Tags: measure-theory

An exercise sheet for my course 'Probability and Measure' gives an outline of the proof of Tonelli's theorem. To start, we need to show the following.

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a ring on a non-empty set $\Omega$. Suppose one has 
 $\Omega \in \mathcal{R} \subset \mathcal{L} \subset 2^{\Omega}$
 such that
$\mathcal{L}$ is closed under complements and increasing countable unions. Show that $\mathcal{L}$ contains
the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{R}$.

Hint: Suppose that $\mathcal{L}$ is the smallest collection of sets satisfying the assumption. Look
at the sets
$$\mathcal{L}' = \{ B \in \mathcal{L} | \forall E \in \mathcal{R} : B \cap E,B \cup E \in \mathcal{L} \} $$
$$\mathcal{L}'' = \{ B \in \mathcal{L} | \forall E \in \mathcal{L} : B \cap E,B \cup E \in \mathcal{L} \} $$
Argue first that $\mathcal{L}' = \mathcal{L}$, and then $\mathcal{L}'' = \mathcal{L}$. Conclude that $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I have been able to show that $\mathcal{L}$ must contain all countable unions and intersections of elements of $\mathcal{R}$, but I'm stuck on how to continue.

Can anyone please help?